# Using vagrant and chef-solo, how can I specify which version of ruby to run?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, chef-infra, vagrant, chef-solo

I'm using chef-solo to provision a new vagrant VM. It's Ubuntu 12.10. Chef runs fine the first time, but fails to launch anytime thereafter.

The problem is that chef-solo needs to run using ruby 1.9.3, but one of my cookbooks installs ruby 2.0.0. It links the new version of ruby to /usr/local/ruby, so the system version is still available at /usr/bin/ruby.

The shebang line in /usr/bin/chef-solo is `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`.

Is there a way I can set an environment variable in the Vagrantfile before chef-solo runs? Or is there another way to force vagrant to run chef-solo using /usr/bin/ruby?

UPDATE: I'm currently using the following command on the VM as a work-around:

```
sudo /usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/chef-solo --config /tmp/vagrant-chef-1/solo.rb --override-runlist "my_runlist"
```

I'd like to force Vagrant to run something similar when I type `vagrant provision` on the host.

Comment: chef-solo runs in your VM - do you want to control which Ruby version is used there or on your host maschine?

Comment: On the VM. I added a clarification/workaround to the question above.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/env` works by using $PATH to find the executable.  You should make sure that `/usr/bin/ruby` is at the front of your path.  One way to ensure this is:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

..and then try your chef-solo run.

Here's more from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#Portability

> Often, the program /usr/bin/env can be used to circumvent this
> limitation by introducing a level of indirection. #! is followed by
> /usr/bin/env, followed by the desired command without full path, as in
> this example:
>
> ## !/usr/bin/env sh
>
> This mostly works because the path /usr/bin/env is commonly used for the env utility, and it invokes the first sh found
> in the user's $PATH, typically /bin/sh, if the user's path is
> correctly configured.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to set the PATH variable in the context of `vagrant provision` run. Globally adding /usr/bin before /usr/local/bin would be counterproductive and would defeat the purpose of the /usr/local convention.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like setting PATH for `vagrant provision` is really what you need.  You might want to try using the shell provisioner to wrap a chef-solo run using a different path.

Comment: Instead of trying to change what vagrant does (and suits most users) you may think about using a ruby version manager like RVM or rbenv or installing Chef ("Omnibus" Installer: http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/) in an encapsulated environment as a binary that comes bundled with it's own version of Ruby

Comment: @cmur2 Using rbenv is a very good suggestion. In fact, the chef-rbenv cookbook even includes a 'vagrant' recipe that resolves this very problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [vagrant omnibus plugin](https://github.com/schisamo/vagrant-omnibus) you can install Chef Omnibus which has its own embedded Ruby, to guarantee that Chef runs always use the same Ruby version.

The only issue I found with this is that if your recipes rely on the system version of ruby some setups won't work correctly (for instance, a ruby installed in `/usr/local/bin` won't be use if you `shell_out!` in a cookbook, but an intallation in `/usr/bin` will).